# Debugging Help: Ruby on Rails File Saving Failed with S3 and Carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I can't figure out for the life of me why this isn't working. I need debugging help and I am new to ruby on rails.

I want to store just a simple s3 file to my amazon bucket. That's it. I don't need this file attached to any row in a controller or stored in a database like all the examples show. I just need it to put it in the bucket. I think I might need to overwrite the store_dir in the avatar uploader but I wouldn't know how.

Below is what I have

The View:

```
= form_tag import_orders_path, :class => 'order-uploads', :multipart => true do
    = file_field_tag 'upload[file]'
    / :file for just getting param[:file] from server
    %br
    = submit_tag "Import CSV", :class => 'submit-file'
```

The Controller:

```
 uploader = AvatarUploader.new
 puts YAML::dump(params[:upload][:file].path)
 uploader.store!(params[:upload][:file])
```

File Path name:

```
/tmp/RackMultipart20150115-9225-o2c5hp
```

avatar.rb uploader

```
# encoding: utf-8

class AvatarUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  # Choose what kind of storage to use for this uploader:
  storage :fog


  # Override the directory where uploaded files will be stored.
  # This is a sensible default for uploaders that are meant to be mounted:
  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

end
```

carrierwave.rb initializer

```
require 'fog'
require 'carrierwave'

CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.fog_credentials = {
    :provider               => 'AWS',                        # required
    :aws_access_key_id      => 'my_key_id',                        # required
    :aws_secret_access_key  => 'my_secret_key',                        # required
    :region                 => 'us-east-1',                  # optional, defaults to 'us-east-1'
  }
  config.fog_directory = "my_bucket"
end
```

Error:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass):
  app/uploaders/avatar_uploader.rb:16:in `store_dir'
  app/controllers/orders_controller.rb:18:in `import'



NoMethodError (undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass):
  app/uploaders/avatar_uploader.rb:16:in `store_dir'
  app/controllers/orders_controller.rb:18:in `import'
```

Comment: your `store_dir` references a model and its id, fix that and this should go away

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you uploaded file should be

It should be `app/uploaders/avatar_uploader.rb`

```
class AvatarUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

 # Choose what kind of storage to use for this uploader:
 storage :fog

end
```

Then

```
 uploader = AvatarUploader.new
 uploader.store!(my_file)
 uploader.retrieve_from_store!('my_file.png')
```